# HistTimeFormat error showing message when opening terminal

Tags: command-line, bashrc

In order to record date and time for each command in history I set

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"
```

And in order for this setting to remain after I log out or close the terminal I added to the .bashrc

```
echo "HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"" >> .bashrc
```

I tested and it shows the time for commands in history,for those I used after I wrote the 2 commands above.Problem is after I open the terminal it gives me a message saying:

```
bash:fg:no job control

HISTTIMEFORMAT = "%d/%m/%y %T"

bash:fg:no job control  

HISTTIMEFORMAT = "%d/%m/%y %T"

bash:fg:no job control
```

I checked the history and it doesn't show me the date for the past commands anymore as it was supposed to do after I added to the bashrc file. I repeated the commands for the time format and each time it doesn't save and I think the more I add the command to the bashrc file the more that message is being expanded with that no job control thing.

Is there any way to fix this/reset the format? There is no whitespace around = and each time I insert that var to the file the more statements of no job control shows after I open the terminal even though it shows time during the session.It's like the var gets broken when exiting.

The end of the bashrc file is this:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%d/%m/%y %T
```

Comment: Your `echo "HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"" >> .bashrc` will result in this being added to your .bashrc `HISTTIMEFORMAT=%d/%m/%y %T` (no quotes) which is why you are seeing the error. So just manually edit your .bashrc file and edit it to ensure you have only a single `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"`

Comment: I read the file with cat .bashrc and it shows exactly what u mean,there is no echo before the var.I was told i need to write that command so the histtime would  be active permanently.

Comment: Edit your original question and add your entire .bashrc file to it.

Comment: As I said previously `HISTTIMEFORMAT=%d/%m/%y %T` (no quotes) needs to be `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"` (with quotes).

Comment: @Cristi quite sure it won't add timestamp on past command just future commands.

Comment: It is meant for the future commands yes,not for  those I used before this setting.It is odd though it did not write it with quotes.

Comment: bash reads quotes **from** left to right so... left right... first string will be `"HISTTIMEFORMAT="` and middle part will be unquoted `%d/%m/%y %T` (the space will break the assignment of the variable) and last is `""` empty. It should have been `echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: ...next, you need to logout in or `source ~/.bashrc` to activate your new settings.

Comment: @bac0n thanks a lot.Your command fixed  it! And ty for the explanation.No friend of mine knew this.Some of them actually recommended me to install zsh or ohmyzsh to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should've been written like this in order to be under quotes in bashrc file

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"' >> ~/.bashrc
```